# Susy 2.0.0.alpha.6 - Undefined mixins 'at-breakpoint','remove-nth-omega'

Tags: sass, susy-compass, compass-sass

Using:

- susy (2.0.0.alpha.6)
- sass (3.3.0.rc.2)
- compass (1.0.0.alpha.17)

with the following SCSS:

```
$susy: (
    columns: 12,
    column-width: 5em,
    gutter-width: 1em,
    gutter-position: after,
    grid-padding: gutter-width,
);

$small: 36em;
$medium: 50em;
$large: 65em;

.hlt-container{
    @include at-breakpoint($small) {
        @include span(6);
        @include nth-omega(2n);
        margin-bottom: gutter(12);
    }

    @include at-breakpoint($small $large) {
        &:last-child:nth-child(odd){
            float: none;
            clear: both;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
    }

    @include at-breakpoint($large) {
        @include span(4);
        @include remove-nth-omega(2n,12);
        @include nth-omega(3n);
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

I first get the error:
`error source/scss/style.scss (Line 10 of source/scss/01-molecules/02-blocks/_00-highlight-block.scss: Undefined mixin 'at-breakpoint'.)`

If I remove the `at-breakpoint` styles, It moves on and chokes again on `remove-nth-omega`:
`error source/scss/style.scss (Line 26 of source/scss/01-molecules/02-blocks/_00-highlight-block.scss: Undefined mixin 'remove-nth-omega'.)`

I've searched through docs and Googled everything I could think of, but can't seem to find issues, like perhaps `at-breakpoint` and `remove-nth-omega` being deprecated with Susy Next.

**EDIT:**

If I change back to

- compass (0.12.2)
- sass (3.2.12)
- susy (1.0.9)

(thank goodness for RVM & gemsets)

and revert the .scss to reflect older Susy syntax:

```
$columns: 12;
$column-width: 5em;
$gutter-width: 1em;
$gutter-position: after;
$grid-padding: $gutter-width;

$small: 36em;
$medium: 50em;
$large: 65em;

.hlt-container{
    @include at-breakpoint($small) {
        @include span-columns(6,12);
        @include nth-omega(2n);
        margin-bottom: gutter(12);
    }

    @include at-breakpoint($small $large) {
        &:last-child:nth-child(odd){
            float: none;
            clear: both;
            margin-right: auto;
            margin-left: auto;
        }
    }

    @include at-breakpoint($large) {
        @include span-columns(4,12);
        @include remove-nth-omega(2n);
        @include nth-omega(3n);
        margin-bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, both of those mixins are being deprecated in Susy 2.0, so neither is available in alpha. We haven't built a clean upgrade path yet, but I promise there's one on the way.

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply. Are there equivalents for these deprecated mixins in Susy 2.0? I'd like to keep using it and getting familiar with it, rather than reverting back to 1.0.

Comment: There are not direct equivalents yet. (1) For `at-breakpoint` we're working on integration with the [Breakpoint plugin](http://breakpoint-sass.com). See the [issue on github](https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/256). (2) Both `nth-omega` and `remove-nth-omega` are simply being dropped, because they end up being more complex than the code they replace. Instead: write an nth-child selector in sass, and then include omega within that. (3) I don't think `remove-omega` exists in the alpha yet. That should have an issue filed. (4) There is a smoother upgrade path in-the-works for 1.x users.

Answer (score 11):

if you want to use the old susy syntax then write:

```
// With Susy 2 installed...
   @import "susyone";
```

instead of

```
// With Susy 2 installed...
   @import "susy";
```

I had this same problem with at-breakpoint and once I switched over it was fine. > [susy documentation](http://susydocs.oddbird.net/en/latest/susyone/?highlight=breakpoint)